# Limit re-ordering of UICustomViewCells to certain cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

**SETUP: Swift 3 / iOS 9+**

I have a simple `UICollectionView` with six cells. The cells are considered empty if they do not contain images. Non-empty cells can be swapped via `Delegates` and `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. This all works fine.

However, non-empty cells can be dropped into empty ones. `UICollectionView` does not know they're empty, which means that while I can prevent them from being dragged, I can't prevent non-empty cells from being dropped **into** empty cells. I have it setup this way because I don't know of a better way to have non-active placeholder cells appear in the UI. I can disable user interaction for empty cells, but they become destination candidates for `collectionView(..moveItemAt..)` regardless when `collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem()` starts.

How can I limit dropping on certain cells? `UITableView` has a way to do this with proposed destinations, but `UICollectionView` doesn't have this. I either need to find a better way to have placeholder cells that are completely inactive, or find a way to prevent the gesture handler from dropping into certain cells.

[image]

Comment: can you add some code??